# SQL Server : get occurrence of each string in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server and I want to get number of occurrences of each string in the table. For this I wrote the following query:

```
declare @tag table (TagName nvarchar(255), total int)

insert into @tag 
    select Tagname, count(TagName) Total 
    from tblTrend 
    where DigTagValue = 1 
    group by Tagname

select * from @tag
```

The output returned is:

```
TagName        Total
----------------------
P1Conv_Trip      1
P2Conv_Off       1
P2Conv_Trip      1
P3Conv_Off       1
Q1Conv_Off       1
Q2Conv_On        1
Q2Conv_Trip      1
Q3Conv_Off       2
Q3Conv_On        2
Q3Conv_Trip      1
W1Conv_Off       2
W1Conv_On        4
W1Conv_Trip      1
W2Conv_On        2
W2Conv_Trip      1
W3Conv_Off       1
W3Conv_On        1
W4Conv_Off       1
W4Conv_Trip      1
W5Conv_Off       1
W5Conv_On        2
W5Conv_Trip      1
```

But the output I want should be like this:

```
TagName    ON    OFF    TRIP
------------------------------
  P1       0      0      1 
  P2       0      1      1
  P3       0      1      0
  Q1       0      1      0
  Q2       1      0      1
  Q3       2      2      1
  W1       4      2      1          
  W2       2      0      1
  W3       1      1      0
  W4       0      1      1
  W5       2      1      1
```

How to achieve this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use temp table. Try this query

```
select
    Tagname, [On] = count(case when suffix = 'On' then 1 end)
    , [Off] = count(case when suffix = 'Off' then 1 end)
    , [trip] = count(case when suffix = 'trip' then 1 end)
from (
    select 
        Tagname = left(Tagname, 2)
        , suffix = substring(Tagname, charindex('_', Tagname) + 1, 4)
    from 
        tblTrend
    where
        DigTagValue=1
) t
group by Tagname
```

Comment: This really worked perfect for me. Kindly describe the solution  count(case when suffix = 'On' then 1 end) what does it means. why after then there is written 1

Comment: It's conditional aggregation. `Suffix` value can be one of `On, Off, Trip`. `Case + Count`  is used to count each one seperately. For example, `case when suffix = 'On' then 1 end` will return 1 if `suffix = 'On'`, else null. And `count` function counts how many times non null value occurs

Comment: @ uzi Thanx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I considered only part of your data, to show the logic :)):

```
declare @x table(TagName varchar(30), Total int)
insert into @x values
('P1Conv_Trip',1),
('P2Conv_Off',1),
('P2Conv_Trip',1),
('P3Conv_Off',1),
('Q1Conv_Off',1),
('Q2Conv_On',1),
('Q2Conv_Trip',1),
('Q3Conv_Off',2),
('Q3Conv_On',2),
('Q3Conv_Trip',1)

select [Tag],
       MAX(case when [status] = 'On' then [total] else 0 end) [ON],
       MAX(case when [status] = 'Off' then [total] else 0 end) [OFF],
       MAX(case when [status] = 'Trip' then [total] else 0 end) [TRIP]
from (
select SUBSTRING(TagName, 1, 2) [Tag],
       SUBSTRING(TagName, 8, LEN(tagname)) [Status],
       Total
from @x
) a group by [Tag]
```

Comment: can you please describle your question that why you use Max function?

Comment: Thanx, It works fine for me. would you please describle your question that why you use Max function?

Comment: @SunnySandeep If it works for you, decide which solution is better and accept right one. When using `GROUP BY` it's necessary to use some aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PIVOT as below:

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        LEFT(TagName,2) AS TagName,
        SUBSTRING(TagName,CHARINDEX('_',TagName,0)+1,LEN(TagName)) AS ActionName,
        Total
    FROM @tblTest
)

SELECT 
    TagName,
    SUM(ISNULL([On],0)) AS [ON],SUM(ISNULL([Off],0)) AS [Off],SUM(ISNULL([Trip],0)) AS Trip
FROM T
PIVOT (
    MAX(Total) FOR ActionName IN ([ON],[Off],[Trip])
) pvt
GROUP BY TagName
```